# Kafka-connect unable to parse date following a pattern

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am facing the following problem:
I am working on a streaming application that uses Kafka and Kafka-connect to store stream to database.

I have a field with a date `2019-02-05T08:43:57.812Z` and I store it in postgresql in `timestamp with time zone`

I use the following pattern : `transforms.ConvertAlertDatetime.format=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX`

Since it's a streaming application, sometimes I could have: `2019-02-05T08:43:57.8Z` which leads to:

> Could not parse timestamp: value (2019-02-05T08:43:57.8Z) does not match pattern (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX)

Is there a way to use regular expressions or another way to parse :

`2019-02-05T08:43:57.812Z` => `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX`

`2019-02-05T08:43:57.81Z` => `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSX`

`2019-02-05T08:43:57.8Z` => `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SX`

Comment: I think you should modify _date field_ during processing in Kafka Streams, to insure, that the format is proper. It can be achieve with simple mapping.

Comment: I generate the date using `OffsetDateTime.now()`, what do you propose please to avoid having different patterns ?

Comment: How about using unix epoch instead? Avoids any kind of string formatting/parsing problems.

Comment: sorry, unix epoch instead of ?

Comment: Maybe something like this: `OffsetDateTime.now().toEpochSecond()`

Comment: Mmm I get your idea thanks. And if we assume that I can not change the date stored in Kafka, is there any regex that I can use ? or another type of kafka connect transformation?

Comment: So, I have tested the conversion to EpochSecond, but I have a weird result in my table, for this long: 1550240332, I have `1970-01-18 22:37:20.497+00` in my table. Any idea about it?

Comment: @DrissNejjar, you should use pattern without milliseconds.

Comment: The thing is that I use no pattern. I just create a table, where the field is timestamp, and then use kafka connect to transform epochSecond to Timestamp.

Comment: @Robin Moffatt, @wardziniak, finally, with my team, we have decided to use `Instant`, instead of `OffsetDateTime` to avoid any formatting issue.